# Websphere wsadmin script to update JMS provider custom properties update for WebSphere MQ messaging provider

Tags: websphere

I am new to Websphere wsadmin script , can you please help me on below issue .
I want to update the reconnectionRetryInterval for JMS provider (JMS providers > WebSphere MQ messaging provider > Resource adapter properties > Custom properties) using the wsadmin script , please help me on this .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it (Jython code):

```
ras = AdminConfig.list('J2CResourceAdapter', 'WebSphere MQ*').split(lineSeparator)
for ra in ras:
    propset = AdminConfig.showAttribute(ra, 'propertySet')
    props = AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourceProperty',propset).split(lineSeparator)
    for prop in props:
        name = AdminConfig.showAttribute(prop, 'name')
        if name == "reconnectionRetryInterval":
            AdminConfig.modify(prop, '[[value "600000"]]')
```